# What is the difference between "receive" and "deliver" in a distributed multicast?

Tags: distributed-computing, multicast, definition, difference

What is the difference between a process receiving a message and a process delivering a message, in the context of a multicast?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Multicast in distributed computing often assumes that some guarantees, such as causal order, are provided by a protocol layer between the network and the application. This protocol layer might delay messages that have arrived from the network, omit messages, use additional control messages, ... Usually, this is the most important layer, where interesting algorithms are needed.

In this context, when describing such algorithms, *receive* (and send) is the interface between the protocol layer and the underlying network channels. *Deliver* (and multicast) is the interface between the protocol layer and the application. It is thus a naming convention to make it easy do distinguish message arrival at different layers, instead of having to say "received at the protocol" (aka *received*) and "received at the application" (aka *delivered*).

An example: Assume that you are enforcing causality and have `m1->m2`. Now assume that `m2` arrives to (i.e. is *received* by) process p before `m1`. `m2` cannot be shown to the application (i.e. *delivered*) immediately. It can only be *delivered* after `m1` is *received* and then *delivered* first.